# Using multiple domain table how we can create a common group table?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-administration

**scenario** :
I have multiple domain table like customer , commodity , location etc etc... those domain table can be added in feature also.

Now I have to create groups using those domain table data in a generic way.

By generic way I mean to say , I can not create one group table for location , one for Customer. Rather I have to create a single group table which will contain all group information irrespective of data used to create group.

Some time it can be a group of customer , some time it can be a group of location or commodity.
Like ...
Customer A , Customer B and Customer C , from customer table, will be construct a group "SuperCustomerGroup" same way may be Location A and Location B , from location table, will be member of "BestLocationGrop" , like wise commodity A and commodity B , from commodity table, will construct a group called "AgriculturalComodityGroup" something like.
All group definition, irrespective of group type and domain data used to construct the group,  I have to keep in one single group mapping  table.

Two IMP Points need to remember:

1. this domain table can be added in feature also.
2. Group Can construct using sub group also
3. Group can be interdomain also (lets say , one group named "someSpecialGroup" can contain "SuperCustomerGroup" and "BestLocationGrop" , given in the above example)

**What I did :**

I design the table following way which solving the purpose to some extent , but not solving the complete problem statement.

```
CREATE TABLE COMMODITY (
COMMODITY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
COMMODITY_CODE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
COMMODITY_NAME VARCHAR(500),
IMO_FLAG CHAR(1),
UD_FLAG CHAR(1),
CREATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CREATED_DT DATE NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP DATE NOT NULL,
ACTIVE CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (COMMODITY_ID)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
LOCATION_ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
LOCATION_NAME VARCHAR(250),
LOCATION_TYPE VARCHAR(100),
PRIORITY INT,
LOCATION_LATITUDE VARCHAR(250),
LOCATION_LONGITUDE VARCHAR(250),
CREATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CREATED_DT DATE NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP DATE NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE GROUP_MAPPING (
GROUP_MAPPING_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL,
ENTITY_TYPE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ENTITY_ID INT NOT NULL,
CREATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CREATED_DT DATE NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_MAPPING_GROUPS FOREIGN KEY (GROUP_ID) REFERENCES GROUPS (GROUP_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_MAPPING_LOCATIONS FOREIGN KEY (ENTITY_ID) REFERENCES LOCATION (LOCATION_ID) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
CONSTRAINT FK_GROUP_MAPPING_COMMODITIES FOREIGN KEY (ENTITY_ID) REFERENCES COMMODITY (COMMODITY_ID) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
CONSTRAINT CHK_GROUP_MAPPING_ENTITY_TYPE CHECK (ENTITY_TYPE IN ('Location', 'Commodity'))
);
```

As we can see "ENTITY_ID"  and "ENTITY_TYPE" is the mapping element in this case with domain table (in our example commodity and location) and group table.

I create a FK relationship also with location table ID and commodity table ID with this ENTITY_ID column in group mapping table.

But the problem is that in this approach is if new domain table added in feature, we have to add that table PK in that group table as fk which I think is not good way to solve it, as every time we have to change in DDL for new domain addition.

Any one can suggest any better approach in table design to solve this problem.